PyArrow memory relationship between write_dataset max_open_files and scanner batch_readahead and fragment_readahead
Question summary:  I am using pyarrow.dataset scanner and write_dataset.  Knowing the average size in memory of a record read from a parquet file, how do I choose the values of batch_readahead, fragment_readahead, batch_size and max_open_files so as to maximize available system resources without hitting OOM?
I have a number of parquet files with very small row-groups.  I am using pyarrow.dataset to scan the files and then write them out using larger row-groups.  The basic logic is pretty straightforward:
dataset = ds.dataset(INPATH, format='parquet')
scanner = dataset.scanner(
    batch_size=batch_size,
    batch_readahead=batch_readahead,
    fragment_readahead=fragment_readahead
)
ds.write_dataset(
    dataset,
    base_dir=OUTPATH,
    format='parquet',
    max_open_files=max_open_files,
    max_rows_per_file=maxrecords,
    min_rows_per_group=batch_size,
    max_rows_per_group=batch_size,
)

I want to optimize the values of batch_readahead, fragment_readahead, batch_size and max_open_files so as to maximize available CPU/RAM.
I have a function that samples my input files and determines the average size in memory of a record, call this avg_rec_size. (Sampling because parquet file metadata only seems to show serialized sizes, which are much smaller than in-memory sizes).
I find that when I keep batch_readahead, fragment_readahead and max_open_files to 1 that memory usage seems predictable as some function of batch_size and avg_rec_size.  But memory consumption is much lower than what's available, so I want to increase batch_readahead, fragment_readahead and max_open_files so as to speed up the process and make full use of available resources.
However, I'm unable to understand the relationships between all these variables.

is the number of scanner batches and files being read a multiple of max_open_files?  In other words, if batch_readahead and fragment_readahead are both 1, is the scanner reading 1 batch for each file being written by write_dataset, or 1 in total irrespective of max_open_files?
if batch_readahead and fragment_readahead are both equal to 2, does that mean there are four batches being read in parallel (2 batches x 2 file fragments)?  Or just two batches being read in parallel (one batch per file)?

